# "symbol" and "markers" don't seem to work anymore in the line function of plotly-express

Tags: python, plotly

In the [website of plotly express](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/), there is an example to use "symbol" and "markers" as an argument for the line function :

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Oceania'")
fig = px.line(df, x='year', y='lifeExp', color='country', markers=True)
fig.show()

import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Oceania'")
fig = px.line(df, x='year', y='lifeExp', color='country', symbol="country")
fig.show()
```

These two examples don't work for me :

```
line() got an unexpected keyword argument 'markers'

line() got an unexpected keyword argument 'symbol'
```

Would you know why ? Is there an alternative ?

Comment: works fine for me. plotly '5.2.2'.  just upgraded to 5.3.1 and it works in newer version too

Comment: this was added in 5.2.1 https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-py-5-2-1-trendlines-ecdf-plots-markers-on-lines-sharper-webgl-legend-group-titles/55681

Comment: Thanks @Rob Raymond. And would you know how to update plotly ? I tried pip install plotly-express==5.2.1 but I get an error : ERROR: No matching distribution found for plotly.express==5.2.1

Comment: `pip install --upgrade plotly` Plotly Express is a sub-package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Rob Raymond comment, the solution was to update plotly :

```
pip install --upgrade plotly
```

Answer (score 0):

In case ones use anaconda, channel plotly needs to be specified:

```
conda update -c plotly plotly
```